# Run code when "foreign" object is added to set

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a foreign key relationship in my Django (v3) models:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # this is irrelevant for the question here
    not_before = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...

class ExampleItem(models.Model):
    myParent = models.ForeignKey(Example, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    execution_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ....
```

Can I have code running/triggered whenever an `ExampleItem` is "added to the list of items in an `Example` instance"? What I would like to do is run some checks and, depending on the concrete `Example` instance possibly alter the `ExampleItem` before saving it.

**To illustrate**

Let's say the `Example`'s class `not_before` date dictates that the `ExampleItem`'s `execution_date` must not be before `not_before` I would like to check if the "to be saved" `ExampleItem`'s `execution_date` violates this condition. If so, I would want to either change the `execution_date` to make it "valid" or throw an exception (whichever is easier). The same is true for a duplicate `execution_date` (i.e. if the respective `Example` already has an `ExampleItem` with the same `execution_date`).

So, in a view, I have code like the following:

```
def doit(request, example_id):
    # get the relevant `Example` object
    example = get_object_or_404(Example, pk=example_id)
    # create a new `ExampleItem`
    itm = ExampleItem()
    # set the item's parent
    itm.myParent = example  # <- this should trigger my validation code!
    itm.save()              # <- (or this???)
```

The thing is, this view is not the only way to create new `ExampleItem`s; I also have an API for example that can do the same (let alone that a user could potentially "add `ExampleItems` manually via REPL). Preferably the validation code must not be duplicated in all the places where new `ExampleItems` can be created.

I was looking into `Signals` ([Django docu](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/)), specifically `pre_save` and `post_save` (of `ExampleItem`) but I think `pre_save` is too early while `post_save` is too late... Also `m2m_changed` looks interesting, but I do not have a many-to-many relationship.

What would be the best/correct way to handle these requirements? They seem to be rather common, I imagine. Do I have to restructure my model?

Comment: may be you can profide onetoone relation between your models and use your own custom validators along with using model forms.

Comment: Look up signals. `Example` could listen for an `ExampleItem` pre-save signal. (Don't ask me for details, that's about all I know!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution here is to put this code in the `ExampleItem.save()` method - just beware that `Model.save()` is not invoked by some queryset bulk operations.

Using signals handlers on your own app's models is actually [an antipattern](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/) - the goal of signal is to allow for your app to hook into other app's lifecycle without having to change those other apps code.

Also (unrelated but), you can populate your newly created models instances directly via their initializers ie:

```
itm = ExampleItem(myParent=example)
itm.save()
```

and you can even save them directly:

```
# creates a new instance, populate it AND save it
itm = ExampleItem.objects.create(myParent=example)
```

This will still invoke your model's save method so it's safe for your use case.

Comment: I see the reasoning here. However, a quick test indicates that `itm.myParent = example` followed by `itm.save()` (in a view) does *not* trigger `Example`'s `save()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Of course it doesn't trigger `Example.save()`. Did I say it would ??? My suggestion is to put your validation code __in `ExampleItem.save()`__. The item has access to its "parent" example instance. Then you can either put your validation code directly in `ExampleItem.save()` or put it in some `Example.validate_item(self, item)` method and call `self.myParent.validate_item(self)` from `ExampleItem.save()`.

Comment: I am sorry, somehow I misread your answer and *meant* you suggested to override `Example`'s `save()`. Doing that for `ExampleItem` makes much more sense of course and is working nicely so far.